# MySQL: Find users with no submission

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, not-exists

I'm struggling a little bit with a query and hope you can help.
I have two tables. On with all the users and one with information from submitted forms.
Both contain the user ID. 
What I would need to find out is which user from the users table does not appear on the report table.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT u.ID, u.display_name, u.user_email, r.user_id
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN report AS r ON u.ID = r.user_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * 
    FROM report AS rr
    WHERE u.ID = rr.user_id
)
```

This seems to be fine for the users who absolutely have never submitted the form.
But the reports table also contains a date column and I was wondering how I can get this grouped by day.
In the front end then I will hopefully have a table which shows:

```
date: user:
2015-01-01 user a
2015-01-01 user f
2015-01-02 user g
2015-01-02 user a
2015-01-03 user z
2015-01-03 user x
```

Where the users are those who have not submitted the form that day.

Hope you can help. Thank in advance!

Comment: You mean you want the date wise user list who are not exists in report table ?

Comment: How can you get the date from the reports table for users who have no reports?  Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thats why I was wondering if I have to change the table somehow to make it possible. but as Emipro Technologies Pvt. Ltd. said, I was wondering if there is a way I can query all dates that exist in the report table then find users  in the users table who don't have the combination of date / user id.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get a list of users that doesn't have any rows in the report table then you can generate a set that is the Cartesian product of the users and the dates that are present in the report table, and then do a left join with that set and check for null.

The Cartesian set formed by the cross join will contain all possible combinations of dates and users; that is would the report table would contain is all users had added reports on all available dates.

```
select r.date, u.user_id 
from report r 
cross join users u
left join (select r.date, r.user_id from users as u join report as r on u.id = r.user_id)
a on a.date = r.date and a.user_id = u.user_id
where a.date is null
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3fea4/2)

With most other databases this could have been done with a set difference operator (minus or except) instead of a left join.

Answer (score 2):

I'm making assumptions about column names in your report table for this answer:

```
SELECT x.report_date, u.user_id, u.display_name
FROM users u
JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT report_date
  FROM reports
) x
LEFT JOIN reports r
  ON r.user_id = u.user_id
  AND r.report_date = x.report_date
WHERE r.report_date IS NULL
ORDER BY x.report_date, u.user_id
```

Check out this fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/407ac/5

Comment: This works great. Could I add additional columns from the reports table or is that not possible due to the distinct selection of the date?

Comment: You cannot select additional columns from the reports table because you are looking for instances where there is no record in that table.  The SELECT DISTINCT is only there to get a list of possible dates.  The one flaw with this approach is that if there is a date where no one has a report, that date will not show up at all in the results.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I managed to get it done by adding a subquery and getting the location from a third table using the given IDs. The fact that no date shows up when no one has submitted is not really a flaw for me. That would just mean its Sunday or bank holiday and I would not really need to see these dates.

Answer (score 1):

Left outer join with where clause...

Here is a good link ...

http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

```
SELECT * FROM `users`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `report`
ON `users`.`ID` = `report`.`user_id`
WHERE `report`.`user_id` IS null
ORDER BY `report`.`Date`
```

Comment: doesn't solve the op's problem. He wants it to have a filter by date. You can edit you answer to include that.

Comment: @AlanFrancis Like that?  just an Order by right, since group by would not work in his example provided.

Comment: Thanks all. But this basically gives me the same results as my original query just in a different order. Also here I'm selecting all the info from the user column but I would not know on which day who has forgotten to fill out the form. Problem is that users have to fill out this form every day and I would need to be able to see all dates and the users who haven't filled it out. Any ideas? Would I need to change the tables and add some fields to make this work?

Comment: Still working on this believe it or not.  I have two people who need the same thing. haha.   Everything was easy except getting the dang dates right.  Grrr...

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 Really appreciate it!

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 - Look down... both of the answers below from jpw and bobwienholt work :)

Answer (score 0):

Surely you could just pass in the date you wanted to check?

so something like this (using `@reportDate` as the parameter):

```
SELECT * FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN report
ON users.ID = report.user_id
WHERE report.user_id IS NULL
AND report.Date = @reportDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the pairs of users/dates without reports.  Generate all possible rows using a `cross join` and then filter out the ones that exist:

```
select u.*, r.date
from users u cross join
     (select distinct date from reports r) d left join
     reports r
     on u.id = r.user_id and d.date = r.date
where r.userid is null;
```